# Getting ClassCastException while creating wallet

Tags: web3j

## Always getting this exception when I am creating new wallet file

java.lang.ClassCastException org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.BCECPrivateKey cannot be cast to org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.BCECPrivateKey

`public void createWallet() throws IOException, NoSuchProviderException, CipherException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, Exception {
        Web3j web3 = Web3j.build(new HttpService("https://rinkeby.infura.io/your-token));
        Web3ClientVersion web3ClientVersion = web3.web3ClientVersion().send();
        String clientVersion = web3ClientVersion.getWeb3ClientVersion();
        System.out.println(clientVersion);
        String fileName = WalletUtils.generateFullNewWalletFile(
                "ZXCVBNM@abc4",
                new File("C:/Users/NI_PC_8/Desktop"));
        System.out.println(fileName);

}`

Comment: Just tried your code on my machine (Ubuntu) and it is working. Which platform, Java, Web3j versions do you use ? My code is [here](https://github.com/gjeanmart/stackexchange/tree/master/46381-getting-classcastexception-while-creating-wallet) if you want to compare

Comment: I just restarted my eclipse and it is working fine now. Thanks for your support @gerg-jeanmart

Comment: Is there any fix for the same , as the error occurs in some of the systems